# How to view Query jobs submitted via GAE in BigQuery console

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a cron job in GAE. This cron job will create a BigQuery Job and submit it.

When I login into BigQuery console, I don't see this Job. I see only the Job created from BigQuery console not the jobs created via this CRON job.

I want to see whether the job is completed successfully or not. How can see the jobs created via GAE in BigQuery console?

I am using Python in GAE and here is the code snippet of it

```
  job = bigquery_client.run_async_query(job_name, query)
  # We are using Standard SQL
  job.use_legacy_sql = False
  # Start BigQuery job
  job.begin()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `cli tool` to obtain the most recent jobs:

```
bq  ls -j -a --max_results=15
```

running this would display a table with job ids and the respective timing.

```
               jobId                Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration
 --------------------------------- ---------- --------- ----------------- ----------
  bquijob_1864e679_15a84d8878a      query      SUCCESS   28 Feb 07:11:06   0:00:04
  bquijob_770b512_15a84d8122c       query      FAILURE   28 Feb 07:10:35   0:00:00
  bquijob_de0df03_15a84d6a4fa       query      FAILURE   28 Feb 07:09:02   0:00:00
  bquijob_52c4f7d7_15a84d660e6      query      FAILURE   28 Feb 07:08:44   0:00:00
  bquijob_76a2c1be_15a84d5e769      query      FAILURE   28 Feb 07:08:13   0:00:00
  bquijob_7f51dde5_15a84d55afb      query      SUCCESS   28 Feb 07:07:41   0:00:08
  bquijob_34f25864_15a84d50503      query      SUCCESS   28 Feb 07:07:18   0:00:08
  job_Ca0cuRTAjY7MEHAs7vTJMxtVYTs   query      SUCCESS   28 Feb 07:00:47   0:00:09
  job_hHfmcdwyBsPsYF5dDvvOdR1Rmd0   load       SUCCESS   28 Feb 07:00:26   0:00:20
  job_mkiLf_mFHLKSplGJOtg-XDKzvv4   load       SUCCESS   28 Feb 02:52:50   0:00:02
  job_3RsPvttxWwv3SzVoOI9Cv_2yWtA   query      SUCCESS   27 Feb 21:18:40   0:00:08
  job_JLsqJO0NEIlKNac6jkDWbwneGMg   extract    SUCCESS   27 Feb 11:35:04   0:00:17
  job_KOS7vKX4aX0FNbK6dibE7cxzcQA   query      SUCCESS   27 Feb 11:33:44   0:00:37
  bquijob_44046bec_15a802f703a      query      SUCCESS   27 Feb 09:27:48   0:00:07
  job_2qQ6YSWeXaP2y2doONQJsIoga3c   query      SUCCESS   27 Feb 08:53:20   0:00:06
```

Second option is to enable audit logs, and locate the queries under the tables that are automatically created in one of the BigQuery datasets

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs

Comment: Is it not possible to see it in BigQuery console?

Comment: the console is able to see the jobs of the user currently logged in. You need to enable audit report and run SQL queries to see it, it's more complicated.